# wrong number of template arguments

Tags: c++, systemc

I dont have much experience in cpp, let alone systemc.

Why doenst this work?

```
sc_in<sc_uint<8>> a,b;
```

> adder.cpp:5: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
>   adder.cpp:5: error: ‘b’ was not declared in this scope
>   adder.cpp:5: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)

This does work:

```
sc_in<int> a,b;
```

Comment: You're missing a space.  It's `> >` not `>>`

Comment: By the way, compilers can give [much better errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dc1a2495f53c15a).

Comment: Actually `>>` is fine for a c++11 compliant compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++03, you can't have the two `>` characters next to each other because the compiler thinks you're trying to perform a right shift.

It then gets really confused, thinking you mean this:

```
sc_in<sc_uint<(8 >> a), b;
//                  ^ ^ ^
//                  ? | ?   Compiler: "what are `a` and `b`?!"
//                    !     Compiler: "why two arguments?!"
```

*If* you had managed to get that far, it would later complain about the two missing `>` characters before `;`, ironically taking you back to where you started.

**You have to write `sc_in<sc_uint<8> >` instead.**

That's fixed as of C++11.